# Syntax error near comma in Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone please let me know why the syntax error is thrown in below code on line 8:

```
# coding: utf-8
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'

values = {‘grant_type’:‘authorization_code’, ‘code’:’xxxxxxxxxxxxx’,‘redirect_uri’:‘xxxxxxx’,‘client_id’:‘xxxxxxx’,‘client_secret’:‘xxxxxxxxx’}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
result = response.read()
print result
```

The error thrown is:

File "second.py", line 8
    values = {‘grant_type’:‘authorization_code’, ‘code’:’xxxxxxxxxxxxx’,‘redirect_uri’:‘xxxxxxx’,‘client_id’:‘xxxxxxx’,‘client_secret’:‘xxxxxxxxx’}
              ^
Version: python 2.7
OS : Mac

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong kind of quotes you need to use `'` not `‘` and `’`

Comment: You have curly quotes. You need regular quotes. Use a text editor instead of whatever you're currently using. (If you're using TextEdit, I think there's a setting you need to configure.)

Comment: `values = {'grant_type':'authorization_code', 'code':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx','redirect_uri':'xxxxxxx','client_id':'xxxxxxx','client_secret':'xxxxxxxxx'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace quote `‘` and `’` with `'`.

Comment: What does this add to the comments that were posted before this answer?

Comment: Nothing besides an attempt at rep hogging.